# How can I apply Seasonal Exponential Smoothing forecasting method to hourly data in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast, holtwinters

I am trying to forecast next-day hourly electricity prices for 2016 using the exponential smoothing method. The data-set that I am using contains hourly price data for the period 2014-01-01 00:00 to 2016-12-31 23:00. My goal is to reproduce the results in [Beigaitė & Krilavičius (2018)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8472762)

As electricity price data exhibits multiple seasonalities (daily, weekly, and yearly), I have defined a msts object for the period 2014-01-01 to 2015-12-31

`msts.elspot.prices.2014_2015  <- msts(df.elspot.prices.2014_2015$Price, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168, 8760), ts.frequency = 8760, start = 2014)`

I want to use this msts object to forecast the next day (2016-01-01) hourly electricity prices using the `hw()` function from the `forecast` package and store the point forecasts in the data frame containing the actual hourly electricity prices for the year 2016.

`df.elspot.prices.2016$pred.hw  <- hw(msts.elspot.prices.2014_2015, h = 24)$mean`

However, I am unable to use the `hw()` function as I get the following error message:

```
Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, phi = phi,  : `
Frequency too high
```

After looking online, it appears that the `ets()` function can only accept the parameter `frequency` to be max `24`. As I am working with hourly data, this is much far below the frequency of my data.

Is there a way I can achieve my desired results using the `hw()` function? Are there any other packages/functions that could help me achieve my desired results?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a bit more, I've came across [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361688/holt-winters-function-hw-in-r) where a user wanted to use the `hw` method to forecast half-hourly electricity demand using the `taylor` dataset available in the `forecast` package.

As Professor Rob Hyndman suggest in the response to the linked question, the double seasonal Holt Winters model method `dshw` from the `forecast` package can be used to deal with half-hourly data.

After removing the yearly seasonality parameter (`seasonal.periods = 8760`) in the definition of my `msts` object, I've ran the model and it provided a pretty accurate result.